# Three floated divs expand to fill container width

Tags: html, css

I don't think this is possible in pure CSS. I have three floated elements within a wrapping container and I want the central of the three to be the width of its content and those either side to fill in the remaining gaps left and right of this element.

```
<style>
.wrap {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
.cont {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
}
.c1, .c3 {
    background: blue;
    width: auto;
}
</style>



<div class="wrap">
    <div class="cont c1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cont c2">content</div>
    <div class="cont c3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6eLdboqw/1/

I realise this is trivial in Javascript but I want to know if there's a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this by using CSS tables, with the middle `div` having a width of 1% to 'auto shrink':

```css
.wrap {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  display: table;
}
.cont {
  background: red;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
}
.c1,
.c3 {
  background: blue;
  width: auto;
}
.c2 {
  width: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="cont c1">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="cont c2">content</div>
  <div class="cont c3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In researching an answer i found this blog post for some more info on how the above works. http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout

Comment: does the job, thanks. table-cell handily gives me the vertical-align settings I need too.

Comment: in fact, we should just go back to making websites out of tables!

Answer (score 0):

You could do so using flexbox.

**Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6eLdboqw/3/**

```
.wrap {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    display: flex;
}

.c1, 
.c3
{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.c2
{
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.cont {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;

}
.c1, .c3 {
    background: blue;
    width: auto;
}
```

[`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) is the short-hand property for: `flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis`.
So what we do is: `.c1, .c3` may grow and shrink, but `.c2` may not grow or shrink.